# How to use fgets() in 2d-arrays (multiple dimension arrays)?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *salloc(int x){
    char **pointer;
    int i;
    pointer = malloc(sizeof(char)*x);
    if(pointer == NULL){
     exit(-1);
    }
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        pointer[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
        if(pointer[i] == NULL){
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
return pointer;
}

void Input(int value, char **array){
    for(i = 0; i < value; i++){
        printf("%d ----\n", i);
        fgets(array[i], 20, stdin);
        printf("%d ----\n", i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char **array;
    int value = 2;
    array = salloc(value);
    Input(value, array);
    return 0;
}
```

The general idea, can be that I miss some syntax.
So I want to read in a string with spaces. If I run this for the **value** 2, it will print:

0 ----

0 ----

1 ----

"some string"

and it crashes after I press enter.
If I do this with **value** 1:
it immediately crashes.
However if I replace fgets() with:

```
    scanf("%s", array[i]);
```

it works (except for the spaces).

So how does fgets() work in 2d-arrays?

Because I get it to work in 1d-arrays. And for some reason I can print 1d-arrays from row 2 when the array only has 2 rows, so it should only be able to print from rows 0 and 1 right?

Comment: Can you post the definition/declaration of `array`?

Comment: There is no 2D array. Provide a [mcve] and state your actual problem.

Comment: Also there is a fat bug here: `malloc(sizeof(char)*x);`. Should be `sizeof(*pointer)` or `sizeof(char*)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how `fgets` can be used with a 2D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   5
#define M   10

int main( void ) 
{
    char lines[N][M];
    size_t n = 0;

    while( n < N && fgets( lines[n], sizeof( *lines ), stdin ) != NULL ) ++n;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( lines[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

then the program output will be the same

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

Comment: what does the part != NULL in your while loop mean? Because that can be the solution.

Comment: Otherwise it just rushes to  the last iteration and waits for a string to be read in?

Comment: @LifeisHard The loop is ended either when all elements of the array were filled or some error (for example the end of the file) was encountered.

Comment: is it possible also use  char* lines[N] ??

Comment: @user8920367 In this case you have to initialize each element of the array by the address of a character array where you are going to read data.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof(char)*x);
```

you only allocate `x` *characters* (i.e. bytes), not pointers to characters. Change to

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof(char*)*x);
```

Without the change, you might go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*. And this is exactly what happens in your code, you allocate only *two bytes* to store two pointers, and a single pointer is either four or eight bytes, so you don't allocate enough memory for even a single pointer.

Undefined behavior is a common cause of crashes, but sometimes it might also *seem* to work.

Answer (score 0):

Note also when taking input with `fgets` (or any of the *line-oriented* input functions), `fgets` will read up to, and *include*, the `'\n'` at the end of each line read. You should perform 2 additional tests/operations. (1) you should test that the last character read by `fgets` is in fact the `'\n'` character. If it is not, that will indicate your input was truncated by `fgets` at the length you specified in the second parameter to `fgets`, and additional character remain unread for that line. Without this check and some way to handle lines that exceed the specified width, you next call to `fgets` will read the remaining characters for the *current* line as your *next* line of input.

(2) you should remove the newline included by `fgets` to prevent your strings from containing embedded `'\n'` characters at the end. (if you are simply parsing numbers from the line and not storing it as a string, this can be handled in several different manners). But, for the general case, you use `strlen` to locate the end of the string, and then overwrite the `'\n'` with a *nul-terminating* character.

In addition to the above, it may make more sense to allocate memory for each individual pointer in `array` only after a line of data has been read to prevent over-allocating space in your code. Since you are specifying that the allocation size for each string will be `20`, a simple character buffer of that size can be used to take input, and after confirming input, you can allocate storage for that line in `array`. A short example of your function with the checks included and with allocation included in `input` would be:

```
#define MAXC 20  /* max chars per read  */
...
void Input (int value, char **array)
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    char buf[MAXC] = {0};

    while (i < value && fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        printf ("%d ----\n", i);

        len = strlen (buf);     /* get length */
        if (len + 1 == MAXC && buf[len-1] != '\n') /* validate read */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: chars exceed MAXC, line[%d]\n", i);
        else
            buf[--len] = 0;     /* strip '\n' */

        printf ("%d ----\n", i);
        array[i++] = strdup (buf);  /* allocate/copy */
    }
}
```

Lastly, why choose `void` as the function type? Why not return the number of values read into `array` if values are successfully read into array, or `0` otherwise. This will at least allow some indication of success or failure of your read and provide a way of returning the number of lines allocated back to the calling function.

An example of your code incorporating the adjusted allocation, necessary checks, and useful return types would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 20

void *salloc (int x)
{
    char **pointer;

    pointer = malloc (sizeof *pointer * x);
    if (pointer == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    return pointer;
}

int input (int value, char **array)
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    char buf[MAXC] = {0};

    while (i < value && fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
        printf ("%d ----\n", i);

        len = strlen (buf);     /* get length */
        if (len + 1 == MAXC && buf[len-1] != '\n') /* validate read */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: chars exceed MAXC, line[%d]\n", i);
        else
            buf[--len] = 0;     /* strip '\n' */

        printf ("%d ----\n", i);
        array[i++] = strdup (buf);  /* allocate/copy */
    }
    return i;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, nlines, value = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : 2;
    char **array;

    array = salloc (value);

    if (!(nlines = input (value, array)))   /* validate input */
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++)    /* print input  */
        printf (" array[%2d] : %s\n", i, array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < nlines; i++)    /* free memory */
        free (array[i]);
    free (array);

    return 0;
}
```

**Test Input File**

The following is a test input file where line 1 (the 2nd line) exceedS 20 characters:

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/readarray 10 <../dat/captnjack.txt
0 ----
0 ----
1 ----
warning: chars exceed MAXC, line[1]
1 ----
2 ----
2 ----
3 ----
3 ----
 array[ 0] : This is a tale
 array[ 1] : Of Captain Jack Spa
 array[ 2] : rrow
 array[ 3] : A Pirate So Brave
 array[ 4] : On the Seven Seas.
```

Don't forget to use a *memory error check* program like `valgrind` to validate your use of the memory you allocate and to insure you have freed it when it is no longer needed. Let me know if you have any additional questions.